# How to open an external program and make a click in a button

Tags: c#, .net, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I can open it but I can't perform a click.

I try

```
public RecordProgram()
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\MouseController.exe", @"C:\test1.mcd");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    _calculatorProcess = Process.Start(psi);

    int ct = 0;
    do
    {
        _calculatorAutomationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "MouseController (1,0x)"));
        ++ct;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    } 
    while (_calculatorAutomationElement == null && ct < 50);

    if (_calculatorAutomationElement == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Calculator must be running");
    }
    //This line returns null
    _resultTextBoxAutomationElement = _calculatorAutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "920388"));

    if (_resultTextBoxAutomationElement == null)
    {
        //Ever get null
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find result box");
    }

    GetInvokePattern(GetFunctionButton(Functions.StartPlayBack)).Invoke();
}
```

The prograns run and open the executable with my file load But _resultTextBoxAutomationElement returns null value.

[image]

Comment: What does "920388" mean? Is it supposed to be a Control ID?

Comment: When using UI automation, you should use the UI Verify tool (VisualUIAVerifyNative.exe) instead of spy++, it's much easier to use and especially crafted for UIA support: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920986(v=vs.85).aspx With this tool you can check what's the UI automation property filter to use

Comment: you can try with few other tools like autoIT, test complete etc.. these have a capability you are looking for....